# El selector de identificador css aplica estilos a mas de 2 elementos

Tags: css, css3

Tengo lo siguiente:

```css
#cursiva{
        font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<h1>Titulo de nuestro sitio</h1>
<h2 id="cursiva">Titulo de nuestro sitio</h2>
<h3>Titulo de nuestro sitio</h3>
<h4 class="verde">Titulo de nuestro sitio</h4>
<h5>Titulo de nuestro sitio</h5>
<h6>Titulo de nuestro sitio</h6>

<a href="#" class="verde" id="cursiva">Enlace</a>
                           
<h2>Otro titulo h2</h2>

<p>Lorem Ipsum es simplemente el texto de relleno de las imprentas y archivos de texto. 
<a href="#" class="verde">Lorem Ipsum</a> ha sido el texto de relleno estándar de las industrias desde 
el año 1500, cuando un <span>impresor</span> (N. del T. persona que se dedica a la 
imprenta) desconocido usó una galería de textos y los mezcló de tal manera que logró 
hacer un libro de textos especimen.</p>

<p class="verde">No sólo sobrevivió 500 años, sino que tambien ingresó como texto de relleno en documentos 
electrónicos, quedando esencialmente igual al original. Fue popularizado en los 60s con la 
creación de las hojas "Letraset", las cuales contenian pasajes de <a href="#" class="verde">Lorem Ipsum</a>, 
y más recientemente con software de autoedición, como por ejemplo <span>Aldus PageMaker</span>, 
el cual incluye versiones de Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Como pueden ver tengo un identificador css y lo he aplicado a varios elementos del html, el problema es que los estilos de ese identificador los ha aplicado a los elementos en los que lo he puesto.

La duda es porque esta haciendo esto??, tengo entendido que un **id** solo se aplica a un elemento aun y aunque ese identificador se lo hayamos puesto a otro elemento, o tengo mal entendido ese concepto??

Comment: En CSS no es así. En CSS funciona con todos. Solamente en javascript se debe tener un solo ID.

Comment: Si eso es un problema para tus estilos, mejor usar clases, y no ID

Comment: @NarcisoAifuz entonces el id en CSS funciona diferente que en JavaScript??

Comment: Aunque como ves, funcionan igual aplicándose los estilos donde quiera esté presente el id, es muy mala práctica usarlo como si fuera una clase. Un id tiene la función de identificar un único elemento en tu página, y no debe repetirse en tu documento html. Lo que te comenta narciso es que luego al  llamar `getElementById` o `querySelector("#id")` en Javascript, la salida es impredecible, porque tienes múltiples ids en tu página.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los **ID** se usa para Javascript; y deben ser únicos en el HTML.
Claro, varios ID con diferentes nombres.

```
<div id="uno"></div>
<div id="identico"></div>
<div id="diferente"></div>
```

Pero igual se puede usar esta ID en CSS para definir estilos (pero no es recomendable ni buena práctica).

Si las **ID**s son todas iguales, funcionará todas iguales con CSS, pero no así con Javascript. Javascript solamente identificará el primero:

```
<div id="uno"></div>
<div id="uno"></div>
<div id="uno"></div>
```

Esto tres son válidos para CSS, pero para javascript es válido solo el primero.

Se puede usar las dos formas. Un **ID** para Javascript, y una clase para CSS:

```
<div id="uno" class="iguales"></div>
<div id="identico" class="iguales"></div>
<div id="diferente" class="iguales"></div>
```

El **ID** funciona iguales en CSS y en Javascript. Porque en CSS tendrá estilos, y javascript tendrá una referencia.

La diferencia es que javascript tomará solamente el primer **ID** (en caso de que haya otros iguales).